# Binding ObservableDictionary to ComboBox (WPF)

Tags: wpf, combobox

I would have thought this question would have been answered already, but I am not finding it. I have a simple class:

```
public class BinanceEndpoint : ObservableObject
    {
        private string baseAddress;
        private string socketBaseAddress;

        public string BaseAddress
        {
            get { return baseAddress; }
            set { baseAddress = value; RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(BaseAddress)); }
        }

        public string SocketBaseAddress
        {
            get { return socketBaseAddress; }
            set { socketBaseAddress = value; RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(SocketBaseAddress)); }
        }
    }
```

I am then populating an ObservableDictionary with objects from that class:

```
    private MainViewModel()
    {
 private BinanceEndpoint apiEndPoint;
        private ObservableDictionary<string, BinanceEndpoint> endPoints = new ObservableDictionary<string, BinanceEndpoint>();
        
        endPoints.Add("Binance.com", new BinanceEndpoint() { BaseAddress = "https://api.binance.com", SocketBaseAddress = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443", });
                    endPoints.Add("Binance.us", new BinanceEndpoint() { BaseAddress = 
    
        "https://api.binance.us", SocketBaseAddress = "wss://stream.binance.us:9443", });
                        endPoints.Add("Testnet", new BinanceEndpoint() { BaseAddress = "https://testnet.binance.vision", SocketBaseAddress = "wss://testnet.binance.vision", });
        }
        [JsonIgnore]
                public ObservableDictionary<string,BinanceEndpoint> EndPoints
                {
                    get { return endPoints; }
                    set { endPoints = value; RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(EndPoints)); }
                }

public BinanceEndpoint APIEndPoint
        {
            get { return apiEndPoint; }
            set { apiEndPoint = value; RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(APIEndPoint)); }
        }
    }
```

Then I am trying to populate a ComboBox from using the ObservableDictionary.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding EndPoints}" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=APIEndPoint, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The issue I am having is that the SelectedValue does not update the value of the ComboBox when it is loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid binding to a `Dictionary` in the first place. There is a reason that there is no ObservableDictionary in the .NET library - since the year of release in 2002. I guess we agree that this is not because MS developers didn't know how to implement such a dictionary after all these years.

Your are using `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedValue` wrong. `SelectedValue` returns the value of the property that `SelectedValuePath` is pointing to. `SelectedValuePath` provides a property path on the `SelectedItem`.
When you actively set the `SelectedValue`, then the control will try to find and select the item where the item's property specified by `SelectedValuePath` matches the value of `SelectedValue`.

When `SelectedItem` returns the selected item (instance), then `SelectedValue` returns the value of a property on this `SelectedItem` that is specified using `SelectedValuePath`.

For example: we bind to a `Dictionary<string, BinanceEndpoint>`. To display the `Key` of your `Dictionary` we specify the `DisplayMemberPath` (as an alternative to a `DataTemplate`).
The `SelectedItem` will hold `KeyValuePair<string, BinanceEndpoint>`.
To have the `ComboBox.SelectedValue` return the selected item's `SocketBaseAddress` value, we must set the `SelectedValuePath` to `"Value.SocketBaseAddress"`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding EndPoints}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Key" 
          SelectedValuePath="Value.SocketBaseAddress" />

<!-- Display the selected item's SocketBaseAddress value -->
<TextBlock text="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" />
```

If you want the `SelectedValue` to return the `BinanceEndpoint` instance then set `SelectedValuePath` to `"Value"`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding EndPoints}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Key" 
          SelectedValuePath="Value" />

<!-- Display the selected item's 'SocketBaseAddress' value -->
<TextBlock text="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox, Path=SelectedValue.SocketBaseAddress}" />
```